# Having issues with playing a CBT nugget video on my internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, video

I've been trying to play a cbt nuggets video and all i get is error, i am confused and i need help, the error details is below

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTbARS/5.14.0.19709)
Timestamp: Mon, 2 Jan 2012 11:10:03 UTC


Message: 'Player.controls' is null or not an object
Line: 84
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: file:///F:/Programming%20Videos(CBT%20Nuggets)[torrents.ru]/files/vidplay.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't getting the same error, but instead just a blank page when trying to watch cbt nuggets. I was able to fix it quite easily.

Open a command prompt as an admin. On windows 7, the easiest way to do this is to click on start and search for cmd, then right click cmd and run as an admin.

Then, in the command prompt, navigate to your CD drive (mine is e:), so: 
(without the > of course)

`> E:`

then list the files

`> dir`

And you should see a file named index.hta. You'll want to run this one.

`> index.hta`

IE should open and run the file. It seems to be a security issue with IE that doesn't let it read from the disk. Sure fixed my problem.